# How do I use a class name and an ID in a select statement?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to select this element.

```
<g class="bar" transform="translate(0,311)" id="Vivint"><rect height="23" width="44.269034090909095"></rect><text x="10" y="16.5" style="fill: white;">Vivint</text></g>
```

I'm trying this, but it isn't working.

```
  svg.select('.bar #Vivint')
  .text('goober')
```

Comment: This `.bar#Vivint` is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add space between class and id: .class#id

```js
d3.select('.bar#Vivint')
  .text('goober')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<g class="bar" transform="translate(0,311)" id="Vivint"><rect height="23" width="44.269034090909095"></rect><text x="10" y="16.5" style="fill: white;">Vivint</text></g>
```

Comment: This `.bar#Vivint` is totally unnecessary because the id should unique in the entire markup.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an answer explaining how to correctly assemble the selector using an ID and a class as asked in the question's title. However, having a selector containing an ID plus any other information to identify a single element always carries some serious *code smell*.

An ID is a [unique identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#id)! There must not be any duplicate IDs within a DOM tree. Hence, an ID is always a self-sufficient selector for an element. Over-specifying a selector is at least bad style and may even negatively affect the performance of your query.

Answering the question's body instead of its title your selection of just one element can be simplified to:

```
svg.select('#Vivint')
```

Comment: So, if I have a field that isn't a `class`, but also isn't unique, is there a field-type I should assign it? I was doing ID, but it sounds like those are appropriate only when the value is unique.

Comment: @Cauder That depends largely on your overall setting and your context. There are some ways to do that, the most common one is to assign a class. (Mis-)using some other attribute might work as well in some cases, however, due to browser optimizations, querying by class is almost as fast as using IDs. I probably would opt for custom classes in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `document.querySelector`, and while you have the `id` you can go with `document.getElementById`.

```
document.querySelector('#Vivint')
```

or

```
document.getElementById('Vivint')
```